# I want to compare two calibrations with R... But cannot find the right answer

Tags: regression, ancova, diagnostic

I first want to precise that I spent 2 hours searching for an answer, couldn't find something that was answering my question.

So basically, I ran two calibration with my diagnostic test, so I actually have two set of data that have the same structure. I ran a test in Day 1 and the other on Day 2. I tested 6 different concentrations (in 3 replicates) on both days. So the data is something like y=ax+b with "y" being the signal (absorbance unit) and "x" the concentration used.

My question is: Is my calibration curve on Day 2 equivalent to the calibration on Day 1 ? So I'd like to compare coefficients and say wheter they are significantly different or not. But I can't find the way to do that properly. I read stuff about adding dummy variables for an ANCOVA (which seems like to be the best bet here), but I cannot adapt this to my actual experience... Should I put the value 1 for Day 1 and 0 for Day 2 ?
I really don't know and I'm kind of lost with all of these methods.

I would appreciate some help !

Many thanks in advance.